# SQL Query on replacing element

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a SQL Query. I have 2 tables. Table 1(left table) and Table 2(right table). I want to do a left join. So If a Group in table 1 is found in table 2, we replace it with New Group.
Table 2 has all PRIME Group. There are 2 conditions:

1. If a PRIME (or) SEMIPRIME is there in table 1, we lookup in table 2 and replace group with new group if found.
2. If a PRIME is there in table 1,and does not exist in NewGroup(Table2) we omit that group itself.(highlighted in yellow).

I tried using coalesce(y.Newgroup,x.Group), but how do I include 2 conditions?

[Please refer input tables and expected output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKeaR.png)

I created table here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f019fb942f3aae3d62427a0ac142d639

Comment: Tables must be provided as formatted textual CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO.

Comment: The action needs both UPDATE and DELETE - so 2 separate queries needed.